# дублирование вывода при использовании буферизации в php

Tags: php, mvc, буферизация

*Заранее извиняюсь, если мой вопрос дублируется(хотя я ничего не нашел как на форуме, так и в гугле)*

Я еще начинаю изучать php, и для углубления решил написать свой небольшой фреймворк в архитектуре MVC. В моем классе шаблона имеется метод для возврата html-страницы, использующий буферизацию вывода:

```
public function render(array $vars = [])
{
    extract($vars);
    if (file_exists($this->path)) {
        $content = $this->path; //путь к файлу шаблона, его получаем в контроллере при cоздании экземпляра класса
        ob_start();
        require 'frameworkName/shared/views/layouts/' . $this->layout . '.php';
        ob_end_flush();
        exit;
    } else {
        self::errorCode(404);
    }
}
```

$this->layout - шаблон с базовой структурой документа, одинаковой на нескольких страницах:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/public/main/js/mobile_header.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/main/css/header.css">
    <title>Сервис для работодателей</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="header_body">
        <div id="header_burger" class="header_burger lock">
            <span class="span lock" id="span" ></span>
        </div>
        <nav class="header_menu lock" id="header_menu">
            <ul class="header_list">
                <li>
                    <a class="header_link" href="/index.php">Главная</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="header_link" href="/user">Профиль</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="header_link" href="/user/out.php">Выйти</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<?php require $content; ?>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

код самого шаблона:

```
<div class="quest">
<a class="quest_" href="/competences">Ранжировать компетенции</a>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/main/css/main.css">
```

Суть проблемы: почему-то я получаю вывод шаблона дважды, но только если он не содержит много контента, например шаблон, код которого выше, возвращает мне это:
[image: дублирущийся вывод]
а шаблон авторизации:
[image: нормальный вывод]

в php.ini пробовал отключать/включать буферизацию вывода, результат не менялся

*вопрос получился, наверное, невыносимо-длинным, но я просто не знаю в чем дело*

Comment: А зачем вы вообще используете буфер здесь? Я бы понял, если бы вам нужно было содержимое буфера отправить в переменную или вернуть из функции.

Comment: @ArchDemon планирую расширять этот фреймворк в будущем, потому вполне может понадобиться, и лучше сейчас решить эту проблему чем потом к ней возвращаться, мне кажется

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле проблема была в том, что при использовании `class_exists()` автоматически вызывается автозагрузка классов, также у меня были одноименные шаблон и контроллер (index.php и Index.Ctrl.php).

*Это поведение кажется мне странным и нелогичным, но как бы то ни было, будет уроком.*

Comment: автозагрузчик классов не вызывает методы и функции. Одноименные шаблоны и контроллеры тоже